# EF4: Child reference in Parent Table. How?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4

If I have 2 tables:

```
Parent: Id (PK), ChildId (FK)
Child : Id (PK)
```

(Table names are not representative)

How do I get EF to create the tables so I can add a ChildId to the Parent table?

Everything I do, I get this created instead:

```
Parent: Id (PK)
Child : Id (PK), ParentId (FK)
```

I don't want that as the Child table will be updated independently and the values used in a dropdown list for the Parent to choose from.

I can do the hard stuff but the easy bits have me stumped!

R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say:

> If I have 2 tables:

Then you say:

> How do I get EF to create the tables..

That's a bit confusing. Are you generating the model from the database, doing model-first, code-first?

Based on "the 2 tables", EF should create two entities, "Parent" and "Child".

The cardinality will be: **Child** 1 - 1..* **Parent**.

There will be a navigational property on **Parent** called **Child**, and a navigational property called **Parents** (note pluralization) on **Child**.

Which doesn't really make sense.

I would think a **Parent** should have *many* **Children**.

I think you have your FK's the wrong way around. **ParentID** should be a FK on Child.

Make those changes, update your model then if you still have issues, paste a screenshot of your model and we'll go from there.

Comment: Sorry, the only way I can make the transition from DB to EF is to imagine in my head what the database would be like and go from there (and also DB admins need to be able to make sense of the generated database). Maybe, what I should have said is given the database tables above,, how would I replicate that in EF?

Comment: Aha, I just realied, "Hey, why not create the database tables, generate the model from the database, then take a look at the results!". Oh boy and it's not even Friday yet...

Comment: Yes, i prefer to create the tables first also - where possible. Give it a go as i said above, generate from db, then let me know how you go.

Comment: Final follow-up on this. Generating from the Db is very handy but so is also using that as the basis for refining the model and then using *that* to build a new database. Can be useful when dealing with old databases, like an intermediary stepping stone to getting what you want.